# Rails/ActiveRecord has_one association behavior when setting child to "nil"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

My colleagues and I noticed something about ActiveRecord `has_one` associations that feels wrong/dangerous and doesn't seem to be readily documented.

Suppose we have this set-up:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :subscription
end

class Subscription < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end
```

## Without "dependent: destroy"

```
> user = User.create(name: "Bob")
> user.subscription = Subscription.create(provider: "Stripe")

> user.subscription = nil

   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.4ms)  UPDATE "subscriptions" SET "user_id" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "subscriptions"."id" = ?  [["user_id", nil], ["updated_at", 2017-01-10 19:24:56 UTC], ["id", 2]]
   (2.0ms)  commit transaction
```

## With "dependent: destroy"

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :subscription, dependent: :destroy
end


> user = User.create(name: "Bob")
> user.subscription = Subscription.create(provider: "Stripe")

> user.subscription = nil

   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
    SQL (1.1ms)  DELETE FROM "subscriptions" WHERE "subscriptions"."id" = ?  [["id", 1]]
   (0.7ms)  commit transaction
```

Is this expected behaviour? I'm actually surprised that a SQL call is made at all without explicitly calling `save` or `destroy` or `update`, etc. I'm also confused about why `dependant: destroy` changes behaviour in this scenario.

Is this supposed to happen, and if so, is it documented anywhere? The `dependant: destroy` version seems particularly dangerous.

**This was tested with Rails 5 as well as several versions of Rails 4.**

Comment: As others have stated this is intended behavior or atleast designed behavior [Source Reference for HasOneAssociation#replace](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/has_one_association.rb#L35). In essence you are "replacing" `Subscription` with `nil` and this causes `Subscription#destroy` if `options[:dependent] == :destroy` otherwise it  it nullifies the relationship.  `User#destroy` is handled very similarly [Source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/builder/association.rb#L138)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Is this expected behavior?*

Yes. An example from the [Rails docs on `has_one` associations](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_one):

> Account#beneficiary=(beneficiary) (similar to beneficiary.account_id =
>   account.id; beneficiary.save)

As for `dependent: :destroy`, from the same docs:

> :destroy causes the associated object to also be destroyed

hence the SQL `DELETE` query.

Comment: The docs you quoted for `dependent: destroy` suggests to me that when the parent is destroyed it's association goes with it (as it does). It does not seem to suggest that it would have any affect on the outcome of altering the associated object directly. Am I just looking at this the wrong way?

Comment: I accepted this answer because the doc quote explaining how the setter works for a `has_one` is interesting. However, I personally am going to have to leave with the belief that the behaviour of `dependent: destroy` here is odd and not properly documented. Ah well.

Comment: Reading through [4.2.1.2 association=(associate)](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-one-association-reference) and the other answer, I think you're right that there isn't documentation about the `DELETE` SQL query being fired when setting the association to `nil`. It definitely works implicitly - exact opposite effect of `"When you assign an object to a has_one association, that object is automatically saved"`.

Answer (score 2):

From the [guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-one-association-reference):

> 4.2.5 When are Objects Saved?
>
> When you assign an object to a has_one association, that object is
>   automatically saved (in order to update its foreign key). In addition,
>   any object being replaced is also automatically saved, because its
>   foreign key will change too.
>
> If either of these saves fails due to validation errors, then the
>   assignment statement returns false and the assignment itself is
>   cancelled.
>
> If the parent object (the one declaring the has_one association) is
>   unsaved (that is, new_record? returns true) then the child objects are
>   not saved. They will automatically when the parent object is saved.
>
> If you want to assign an object to a has_one association without
>   saving the object, use the association.build method.